# How to Monitor MYSQL changes

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, intrusion-detection

I have installed `The AIDE` on my Ubuntu server and I would like now to Monitor MYSQL changes (new fields, new content, new tables etc. created). How can I do this with AIDE?

Thanks!
Roman

Comment: not sure what AIDE means , please clarify

Comment: @tawfekov hello it is AIDE - Advanced Intrusion Detection Environment

Comment: What exactly would you monitor with AIDE? The actual files of the database? From what I'm reading AIDE is geared towards files monitoring (config, etc.). I don't think the underlying mysql DB files would be 100% clear text readable. See: http://ustechnica.com/tag/advanced-intrusion-detection-environment/

Comment: @Roman if you are looking for auditing in your application  , there a many libs for that , I wrote one for ZF2 https://github.com/tawfekov/ZF2EntityAudit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a special library (framework or app) I can't see a way for you to do this using AIDE. AIDE would better serve to monitor configuration files, and instead daily dumps of the actual SQL on an offsite server (that also supports versioning).

### **Requirement: I would like now to Monitor MYSQL changes (new fields, new content, new tables etc. created).**

From [here](http://ustechnica.com/tag/advanced-intrusion-detection-environment/) there is a description of what AIDE does:

> "It is a host-based intrusion detection system (HIDS) for checking the
>   integrity of files. It does this by creating a baseline database of
>   files on an initial run, and then checks this database against the
>   system on subsequent runs. File properties that can be checked against
>   include inode, permissions, modification time, file contents, etc."

**Monitoring Changes in Table Content:**

Unless there is a tool to perform parsing based on diffs (between two different binary files), it will not be that easy to understand changes related to new fields, and new content.

Therefore I would propose *an hourly (or daily) mysql dump of your data within a git folder (which provides versioning) and preferebly on a secure offsite server.*

**Monitoring Addition of Tables**

If you wish to detect the addition of new tables, it will be as simple as monitoring the creation of underlying Database files. For example, the IMAP engine creates 3 different underlying files one of these being MYD.